# Techelet vs tzitzit tags

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

There have been a few questions recently regarding techelet. They are tagged with both [techelet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/techelet) and [tzitzit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tzitzit). They don't seem to have to do with tzitzit per se. Should we remove the tzitzit tag from these questions or maybe merge the tags as there aren't so many techelet questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the existing [techelet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/techelet) questions have to do with using the dye contemporarily for the purpose of tzitzit, so I think that both tags fit. I don't think merging the tags is necessary, since there could some day be techelet questions that relate to, e.g. Mishkan uses rather than tzitzit.